# Reading variable length arrays from file

Tags: c, file, text-files

I'm writing a program on C which should access text file to get the prototype function for further computations. Here's a simple example of data stored in such file:

slc 0.5 0.5;

rdf 1.04 1.5 3.4 0.4;

raq 0 0.2 0.44;

jqw 7.23 6.2 0.23 1.56 1.345 1.0;

First comes the unique ID of line i.e. "slc" or "jqw", which will define the contents of array. This is the only purpose of this chars.

The bad thing is that all arrays have different length (say from 2 elements to 60). I would like to enter only ID of line (i.e. "slc") and get all numbers in this line into array.

I would like to ask you about possible strategies for solving this problem. Not really need code, only the effective strategy. For me, the alternative solution is to use known offset and array length for each ID, though this is not the best solution since it complicates edition of txt file (i.e. inserting new line).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of 60 (as you say). Fill it up and make a note of how much that bucket has filled. If you are worried about memory, copy it into the appropriate size (`malloc`). Otherwise just store the 60 floats/doubles with the number in the array for that particular line.

Comment: Thanks for response! Gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

In general , You can use, `scanf` versions, to play with these type of things. Particularly, in these type of examples, we have to think a lot and we have to make an efficient usage of `sscanf`,`fscanf`,`fprintf`,`sprintf` etc...

Particulary, I got interested with this question, and wrote my own program.

I am giving here for you reference.
Just start playing with I/O functions, to attain your goal...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
       FILE* fp = fopen("D:\\LangFiles\\CFiles\\Stackoverflow answers try\\numread.txt","r");
       char a[] = "jqw";
       char digits[50],str[5];       

       if(!fp)
        printf("Reporting error");


       while(!feof(fp)){
            fscanf(fp,"%s %[^;] %*c",str,digits);  //reading the jqw in str and rest in digits and ignoring the ; at the last

            if(strcmp(str,a) == 0){           
               while(1){
                   float float_num;
                   sscanf(digits,"%f",&float_num);  //reading a single digit
                   printf("%f\t",float_num);
                         /*Store or use float_num*/                                                              
                   if(strchr(digits,' '))         //moving the digits ptr to next space                             strcpy(digits , strchr(digits,' ')+1 );  //making digits ptr to point the next char of space
                   else
                       break;  //exiting once the digits is empty
                }

                break; //moving out after our requirement is satisfied
            }

      }      
getchar();         
}
```

All the best.....

Comment: Dont use feof() like this (it will return != 0 **after** the EOF has been hit). Instead, check the return from fscanf(). At least. Even better (and safer, and simpler) is to build a loop around fgets().

Answer (score 0):

Read a complete line with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html).

Keep getting numbers from the line with [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) (or `strtol()` or `strtoul()`) making sure to use the second argument both to check for errors (and/or the `;` for line termination?) and to continue reading numbers.

As for the array, either allocate a "big enough" chunk (60 elements?) or grow it as needed.